# Telerik UI for MVC and ASP.NET CORE Lambda Expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to implement a Kendo grid through Telerik UI for MVC in a ASP.NET Core MVC web app. Trying to use a template column with a lambda expression get the following error, relating to the `@< text >` expression:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

If I start a brand new project using the Telerik templates and paste in the following code, an ASP.NET 4.5 app will run just fine, but ASP.NET Core will return the error.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<dynamic>()
    .Name("Something")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound("ColumnName");
        columns.Template(@<text></text>).Title("LambdaColumn"); @* Error on this line *@
    })
)
```

I believe this is a problem with the change with the new EntityFramework. How can I get the lambda expression to function correctly with EntityFrameworkCore?

Answer (score 0):

What is this bound too `columns.Template(@<text></text>).Title("LambdaColumn"); @* Error on this line *@`

`columns.Bound(yourlambda).Template(@<text></text>).Title("LambdaComlumn");`??

Looking back at its entirely related to the previous line, you can't us string value for the name of the binding, it has to be a lambda.

`//snip`

```
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.LastName).Title("LastName");
        columns.Template(@<text></text>).Title("LambdaColumn"); @* Error on this line *@
    })
```

`//c for column, pneumonic in nature but c is also related to the Type used in creating the grid.   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Customer>())`

`//endsnip`

Also I don't know how well dynamic will work with the grid.. Pretty sure in my experimentation and use of the RadGrid its been rock solid and never seen anything other than concrete types being used in the Grids implementation or documentation

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me!

There shouldn't be anything explicitly bound to the second column. What I'm ultimately attempting to do is this: [Dynamic Columns](http://www.telerik.com/forums/dynamic-columns-based-on-list-in-viewmodel).

You're right that the code isn't very functional. It was just the minimal code that demonstrates the difference between frameworks, since it "works" in asp.net 4 but not asp.net core. The first column was just there so the grid would have two columns when it rendered.

Comment: yea hence the use of the template but I suspect the actual error was in the previous line, is specific to attempt string to lambda conversion which I would expect a stiff middle finger from the compiler, so I bet would work if you give it a lambda in the first line inside the `Bound()` func